# Progress bar change color when width is more then 1

Tags: html, razor

I have that progress bar:

```
@model float

<div class="progress-bar">
<div class="progress-green-bar" style="width: @string.Format("{0}", (int?)(Model / 100.0f));">
</div>
<div class="progress-bar-percent-text" style="text-align: center; color: black; font-size: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color:transparent">
    @((int?)(Model))%
</div>
</div>
```

I see how value in Model is changed in div `class="progress-green-bar"` when debug.
But progress bar change color only if `Model >= 100` and when this happens the whole bar turns green.

I go to this model from here:

```
<div class="update-programs">
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("UpdateProgramsProgress", (float)(ViewBag.Progress ?? 0.0f));
}
</div>
```

Additional this page throw error:

> Cannot convert null to 'float' because it is a non-nullable value type

But I dont know why and how repair that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if Model is from 0 to 100:

```
<div class="progress-green-bar" style="width: @string.Format("{0}", (int?)(Model))%;">
```